# About the closed line integral of electric field intensity

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

In electrostatics, we know that the closed line integral of electric field is zero :

> \begin{equation}
> \oint\limits_{C} \mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{x}\right) \boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\;\;0
> \tag{Electrostatics} 
> \end{equation}

That means the field is conservative in nature.

But in the case of time varying fields the closed line integral of electric field is :

> \begin{equation}
> \oint\limits_{C} \mathbf{E} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\;-\;\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}\int\limits_{S} \mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  d\mathbf{S}=\;-\;\dfrac{\mathrm{d} \Phi}{\mathrm{d} t}
> \tag{Electrodynamics} 
> \end{equation}

that is equal to the negative of time derivative of the magnetic flux.

How is this happend?

Comment: The first line in your question talks about **electrostatic field**. The Faraday's law (or 3rd Maxwell's equation) is given for time-varying electric field, which is evidently not a electrostatic field.

Answer (score 0):

It's prettily answered by [user35952](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/35952/user35952) in his [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263605/about-the-cloesed-line-integral-of-electric-field-intensity#comment584110_263605) above; nevertheless here comes the explanation:

The relation

$$\nabla\times \mathbf E= 0\qquad\qquad:\qquad\qquad \textrm{True only for statics}. $$

The general relation is

$$\nabla \times \mathbf E= -\partial_t\mathbf B\;.\tag 1$$

The static fields were conservative and hence could be expressed *solely* as the gradient of a scalar potential viz.

$$\mathbf E = -\nabla \varphi~_;$$

But, actually the electric field is given by

$$\mathbf E = -\nabla\varphi -\partial_t\mathbf A\;,\tag 2$$ where $\nabla\times \mathbf A= \mathbf B\;.$

So, the fields that are considered in the concerned Maxwell's equation is **different** from those of statics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a confusion . Why the time varying field is not conservative in nature?

Comment: A field is conservative when its $\text{curl}$ is zero.

Comment: Yes I know that. That is why Curl of E is Zero for static condition. But for Time varying condition it is not Zero. That means it is not conservative .